# Is TrueCrpyt still safe, or is VeraCrypt the better option now?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, bitlocker, veracrypt

I know that TrueCrpyt stopped updating a while back and it has a warning saying that it may not be safe due to unpatched security issues. I have a version of windows with Bitlocker, but the fact that it can't make containers like TrueCrpyt could really kills it for me.

I read on another thread about VeraCrypt, which I guess is based off of TrueCrpyt's code, but it has yet to be audited. For a security minded individual, is TrueCrpyt still the better option because it passed an audit, or is VeraCrypt the better option because it is still being updated.

Comment: Welcome. That sounds products recommendation, which thing is [off-topic](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. I think it is better if you ask your question instead on: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I haven't seen TC being cracked yet and it has been audited (http://istruecryptauditedyet.com/). Currently I do not see any reason not to use it (yet).

Comment: @Begueradj it was as much of a software rec as it was a question on the security of cryptographic tools. I thought that this might be the better place to post it because this site focuses solely on security and not software as a whole.

Comment: It's safe, this has been debated before.